# Are electrons immune to scattering in plasma accelerators?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, accelerator-physics

Plasma accelerator is a promising new technology which may increase the acceleration gradient by orders of magnitude. Unlike conventional RF accelerators which operate in high vacuum, plasma accelerators use the wake field of laser pulses or particle beams passing through helium gas to accelerate particles.

Here is my question. Conventional accelerators need to operate in high vacuum to minimize scattering between high energy particle beams and gas molecules, while plasma accelerators operate in helium atmosphere and the particle energy is even higher. Wouldn’t it make scattering even worse?

Electrons are very light, which means when the energy is the same, the Lorentz factor is several orders of magnitude higher than other particles (protons or muons). The high charge to mass ratio makes electrons particularly prone to losing energy via bremsstrahlung or synchrotron radiation.

At high relativistic speeds the field lines of charged particles constrict due to Lorentz contraction, which greatly increases the Coulomb force with passing by ions. That’s why circular electron positron colliders are limited to 500 GeV, above which the beam reusability degrades rapidly.

[image]

If electrons are indeed more vulnerable to scattering, would muons be a better choice? Muons are also elementary particles (which provides a clean background of collisions) but 200 times heavier, which makes their scattering with matters much weaker. Actually muon beams can even penetrate pyramids or mountains which far exceeds the penetration ability of neutrons. The short lifespan of muons may be a problem, but if muons are already highly relativistic upon entering the plasma accelerators it won’t be a big problem.

Comment: So you have to create the muons, and then accelerate them up to highly relativistic velocities before putting them into your accelerator? So what is the point of the plasma accelerator portion?

Comment: To accelerate these muons to energies far exceeding conventional accelerators.

Comment: @JonCuster "Before injecting protons to the LHC, they have to be accelerated to highly relativistic velocities in the SPS before putting them into the LHC... so what's the point of the LHC?" First, all accelerators have upper and lower energy bounds. Second, the goal of an accelerator is to get to high energies, not just to get pretty close to the speed of light. Also, a muon collider (not wakefield acceleration based) is already being widely discussed, and it has the same requirement.

Comment: But the plasma accelerator only shortens the distance needed to accelerate to a given energy (using the larger gradient to reduce the length). It does not change what energy one can accelerate things to.

Comment: Muons have a rest frame lifetime of microseconds. This limits how far they can travel. I understand that LHC takes minutes to accelerate heavy ions and then stores the beam for hours. Is this a limitation for muons that would be helped by a higher acceleration?

Comment: From what I have found on plasma acceleration , it cannot compete with the energies reached by colliders and linear accelerators. The reachable energies of a plasma accelerator of order of GeV at most. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_acceleration